# Background Location Service

Tags: android, service, location

I'm looking for a solution to get location of a device with latitude, longitude and speed parameters. Solution should work on both Android OS 8 and lower version.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library will help you to run service in the background

Comment: if you need it once every n minutes, you can use workmanager from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Answer (score 7):

[Fused Location Provider](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/) is used to get the location in Android.

Here is the step by step procedure to get continuous location using Fused Location Provider using background service.

1) Add location service API in gradle.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

2) Declare all necessary permission in `AndroidMenifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

**android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** and **android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** is used to get the device's location.

**android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE** is used to run service in Android 9.0

3) Create `LocationService` to get continues location.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final long LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL = 10000;
    private static final float LOCATION_REQUEST_DISPLACEMENT = 5.0f;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        showNotificationAndStartForegroundService();

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                //here you get the continues location updated based on the interval defined in
                //location request
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /**
     * Method used for building GoogleApiClient and add connection callback
     */
    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Method used for creating location request
     * After successfully connection of the GoogleClient ,
     * This method used for to request continues location
     */
    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(LOCATION_REQUEST_DISPLACEMENT);

        requestLocationUpdate();
    }

    /**
     * Method used for the request new location using Google FusedLocation Api
     */
    private void requestLocationUpdate() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                //get the last location of the device
            }
        });

        mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
                Looper.myLooper());
    }

    private void removeLocationUpdate() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
    }

    /**
     * This Method shows notification for ForegroundService
     * Start Foreground Service and Show Notification to user for android all version
     */
    private void showNotificationAndStartForegroundService() {

        final String CHANNEL_ID = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat("_notification_id");
        final String CHANNEL_NAME = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat("_notification_name");
        final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE;
            assert notificationManager != null;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        } else {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "GoogleApi Client Connected");
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "GoogleApi Client Suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "GoogleApi Client Failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        removeLocationUpdate();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

In `LocationService` first you have to build `GoogleApiClient` after the request new location using Fushed Location Provider

Here you get the new location in `mLocationCallback`, based on the interval that provide in the `mLocationRequest`.

4) Declare Service in `AndroidMenifest.xml`

```
<service
     android:name=".LocationService"
     android:exported="false" />
```

5) Now Start Service from Activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
     startForegroundService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
else
     startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the similar solution, but location.getSpeed() always return 0.0 value however location always change. Also I'm running the service periodically using alarm manger.

Comment: Have check it in another device, because sometimes device not provide accurate GPS data. I'm using the simulator as well as Real Device and get the proper location data (Speed, latitude, longitude).

Comment: Ok Let me try your solution and check. Should I check the speed inside onSuccess(Location location) or onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult)? and Once I get the location I want to stop the service?

Comment: If you want the last location of the device, then you get in onSuccess(Location location) Method, but if you want continues location updates then you get in onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult). If you want to get the location in future then do not stop service, but you require only once then call method stopService().

Comment: My goal is to get the location and speed after particular time interval that will be set from front end and location will be sent to server only in case speed is greater than 5km/hr.

Comment: Then you should simply set the mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL) from frontend, you will get a new location in that interval.

Comment: If you continues get speed 0.0 then, you also calculate speed base on two latitudes and longitude.

Comment: I have tried two different services to get location and speed, one using the FusedLocationProviderClient and other using the GPS and Internet provider but in  my log, speed is always coming 0.0 however location is changing all the time.

Comment: Should you use Emulator during testing? or any Real Device, If real device then which device you used?

Comment: I'm using moto g5 +

Comment: After setting location mode to High Accuracy, It seems speed start coming.

Comment: Glad to know that it's working. Above code mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); it is already mention

Comment: I think this setting is device specific because some other device you have to simply turn on GPS.

Comment: @ChandanSharma What is the requestLocationUpdate method supposed to contain?

We cannot call ActivityCompat.requestPermissions because we don't have an activity but a service. 

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @John Before start service you have to check location permission ActivityCompat.requestPermissions in activity, and if user grant permission then start service from activity.

Comment: Hi, my location update interval is 15min, so I need the GPS to sleep while not fetching location, so that I can reduce battery drain; but my gps is on all the time ! How can I fix this?